# Rectangular transformation into Polar coordinates

Tags: transformation, polar-coordinates

I was working with a simple transformation of rectangular coordinates - symmetry around the y-axis, i.e. $$f(x,y) = (x, -y)$$  I wanted to express the identical concept in polar coordinates.  After some messing around I remembered f(r, $\theta$) = (r, -$\theta$) gives symmetry around the x-axis, and thus translating the angle $\theta$ both before and after the flip, you could create $$f(r, \theta) = (r, -(\theta - \pi/2) + \pi/2) = (r, \pi - \theta)$$ for the desired result.

My question is, is there a mechanical technique for converting the expression of a function on the plane in rectangular coordinates to an expression of that same function in polar coordinates?

Or do I simply have to 'mess around' each time?  (I went through the standard $x=r* cos (\theta)$ type formulas, but they aren't really the same, are they?  I think I'm talking about operating "on" the plane, instead of operating "in" it?  Or am I overthinking and confusing myself)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You know there is a map, or function, $(r, \theta) \rightarrow (x,y)$, given by $x=rcos(\theta), y=rsin(\theta)$.  There is also a function $(x,y)\rightarrow (r,\theta)$, although the formulas are hard to write down, and they're made especially complicated by the fact that $\theta$ is not well-defined at the origin.

So one "mechanical" approach to your problem would be to express $f(r,\theta)$ as a composition of three functions:

$(r,\theta)\rightarrow (x,y)$

$f$

$(x,y) \rightarrow (r,\theta)$.

But try to compute this for any reasonable function, and you will probably conclude that a more informal approach is usually faster. :)

Comment: I do that and I get (r, theta)->(r,-theta) OR (r, theta)->(r,Pi-theta), depending on which -tan(theta) identity I use.  This has got something to do the smaller period of tangent, right?  If I wanted to nail it mechanically, I'd need to break down the domain based on what atan is doing, right?  Something like what the atan2 function does when programming?

Comment: Yes, remember that the standard range for arctan is $(-\pi /2, \pi /2)$.  A full description of $(x,y) \rightarrow (r,\theta)$ will need to take into account whether $x$ is negative or not.